# Tor and viruses

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, security, tails

I was wondering if you can get a virus by opening some websites of the deep web using Tor? With some links it's hard to tell if they are legit or not, recently I came across some website saying that "exploit was successful" and nothing more...so, it all looks kinda weird. Antivirus showed nothing but can I really be sure that I am safe?

Is Tails a better solution than Tor browser bundle in the case of viruses and exploits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tor Browser Bundle is a modified version of Firefox. It includes some "hardening", tweaks and patches to make it more secure, but many Firefox [zero-day exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_exploit) can still be used against it. The best way to avoid these is to disable Javascript globally with the built-in NoScript add-on. There are comparatively very few exploits of HTML parsing and rendering, so it's extremely unlikely that you'd get identified or infected with Javascript disabled. (Anecdotally, however, see [canvas fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting) for a new and scary exception to this trend.)

As far as I know, though, there isn't any means of transmitting malware through the Tor Browser that doesn't work on standard Firefox.

For a recent and notable example of a Javascript exploit being used to deanonymize users, see this:

http://www.wired.com/2013/09/freedom-hosting-fbi/

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/fbi-tor-exploit/

Note that, in this case, users' computers weren't infected. The exploit only leaked their real IP addresses, which allowed them to be identified and located. Many "Tor specific" attacks are of this nature, as exposing a user's real IP address is not an exploit at all if that's the IP address they're using publicly.

In regards to the page telling you their "exploit was successful", it's much easier to type:

```
<html>
    <p>exploit was successful</p>
</html>
```

Than it is to exploit a hardened up-to-date Firefox browser. It's possible you got infected, but you're probably fine.

Remember to keep your Tor Browser up-to-date, disable Javascript, and follow [these guidelines](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en#warning). If you do, you're about as safe as you can be in a modern web browser.

And, to answer your last question, yes, Tails is safer. It attempts to route all Internet traffic through Tor, so even some exploits that get by Firefox will still not access the real IP. However, as with all security software, Tails does occasionally have exploits of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i will shine a little light on the deep dark web as a hacker myself the idea of hacking is to secretly transfer your code on to a hosts PC for reasons such as ransoming their computer (whether i convince them to buy a fix or directly demand cash)Data mining auto fill credit card information that i can use to make a withdraw. Taking personal or blackmail data to make money, proving a point to a wannabe or if im feeling trollzy and only when im felling trollzy will u ever know that u have been infiltrated unless u have some god lvl firewall that alerts u every time a Nat farts near your pc in which case it will probably be to late by the time your allerted
          But the point im trying to make is trolling means causing the biggest reaction with the smallest about of effort possible

so if i literly tell u that u have been hacked just by going on a site might even ask your pc to give me a name so i can address u properly or put a bunch of computer mombo like [C:/x86/Steam/Steamapps/] contains malicious files your computer will crash shortly the idea is the put the stupidest shit possible and make people believe it

```
 half of defending yourself aganst hacking is in your head
```

if i have your ip and u know u were on the big scary deep dark web with a billion bad guys that might know u and i threaten to give it out to them well your going to pay me of course
         but if u have now one after u and a hacker threatens u with your ip then its more or less "go tell someone who cares because whoever u tell is going to laugh u in the face" because your nobody to nobody on the dark web
         if a hacker feels he can bully u in to giving him money that's the only time your in trouble

```
  so a little advice to all the wana be hackers its ok to explore the dark web but don't go were u don't belong because unlike youtube and the rest of the world if u click on a room that says DeadRoom or RedExtrordinare aka a red room u will find a red room its not click bait and if u act suspicious they will think your the fbi or someone trying to report or arrest them so the best advice i can give u is fit in because the dark web isn't scary its the community u hafto watch out for
```

ok this is a list of key words to watch out for unless your about this life Red (anything red literly guys even down to redtube lol)
(Monkey house) anything to do with clowns(aka juggalos u may see death and shit and if u don't fit in they might get offended)
Drug-Arms(srrsly guys do u really want to give drug dealers from gangs like the cartel your address to mail drugs through a federal system?)
Any cracked Video Game or Any software were u dont know the person directly or offer a reward for honesty (i garentee if it didn't make it to the normal web it has malicious software)
stay away from hyper links given by anyone in any chat room because if u have java installed most links alone can auto download shit without even notifying u at all 
so basically guys theirs no such thing as a Dark Web Torist theirs no gift shops and the sights u might see may kill u for little to no satisfaction so good luck and be safe !!

//This was a rough draft im not going to go back and edit it it has typos Deal with it or don't read it//